# How can I tell the difference between a .gif and a .jpg file using MATLAB or python without having the extension explicitly?

Tags: python, image, matlab, jpeg, gif

I have a database of files "1", "2", "3", etc[...]. They should have been downloaded with "1.jpg", "2.gif", "3.png", but this information wasn't available. My question is how can I get information by opening or reading the file and knowing that it is actually a ".jpg" or if even an image that was saved as 3.jpg is actually a GIF file.

I'd like to script this so I can automate and get the correct extension for a data set of around 20 000 images, so manual one-by-one inspection isn't the solution here.

Comment: [Magic Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures). `ff d8` for JPG, `GIF87a/GIF89a` for GIF.

Comment: also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand more specifically on Lattyware's answer:

Magic numbers:

GIF87a signature
HEX: `47 49 46 38 37 61`
ASC: `G..I..F..8..7..a.`

GIF89a signature
HEX: `47 49 46 38 39 61`
ASC: `G..I..F..8..9..a.`

JPEG signature
Has a couple. To quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29)

> JPEG image files begin with `FF D8`and end with `FF D9`. JPEG/JFIF files contain the ASCII code for "JFIF" (`4A 46 49 46`) as a null terminated string. JPEG/Exif files contain the ASCII code for "Exif" (`45 78 69 66`) also as a null terminated string, followed by more metadata about the file.`